Como se puede optimizar la busqueda y carga de datos en python
Quiero optimizar la busqueda y carga de datos al momento de colocar la seccion de salida de productos tarda mucho tiempo en mostrarme los productos y no son muchos existe una forma mas eficiente de hacerlo? he intentado de varias formas y todas son igual de lentas. La verdad no se si esto es normal o no.
def mostrar_salida_productos(self):
    self._clear_main_frame()
    
    ctk.CTkLabel(
        master=self.frame_principal,
        text="Salida de Productos",
        font=("Century Gothic", 18)
    ).pack(pady=10)

    entry_busqueda = ctk.CTkEntry(
        master=self.frame_principal,
        width=300,
        placeholder_text="Buscar por nombre o código"
    )
    entry_busqueda.pack(pady=10)

    frame_lista = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(master=self.frame_principal)
    frame_lista.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)

    productos = base_datos.obtener_productos()
    
    def actualizar_lista(event=None):
        self._actualizar_lista_productos(frame_lista, productos, entry_busqueda.get().lower())

    entry_busqueda.bind("<KeyRelease>", actualizar_lista)
    actualizar_lista()

    def confirmar_salida():
        self._procesar_salida_productos()
        productos.clear()
        productos.extend(base_datos.obtener_productos())
        actualizar_lista()

    ctk.CTkButton(
        master=self.frame_principal,
        width=220,
        text="Confirmar Salida",
        corner_radius=6,
        command=confirmar_salida
    ).pack(pady=10)

def _actualizar_lista_productos(self, frame: ctk.CTkScrollableFrame, productos: List[Any], query: str):
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    for producto in productos:
        if query in producto[1].lower() or query in producto[2].lower():
            self._crear_item_producto(frame, producto)

def _crear_item_producto(self, frame: ctk.CTkScrollableFrame, producto: tuple):
    frame_item = ctk.CTkFrame(master=frame, corner_radius=6)
    frame_item.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    check_var = tk.BooleanVar()
    ctk.CTkCheckBox(
        master=frame_item,
        text="",
        variable=check_var
    ).pack(side="left", padx=5)

    for text, width in [
        (producto[2], 150),  # Código
        (producto[1], 150),  # Nombre
        (f"Stock: {producto[5]}", 100)  # Stock
    ]:
        ctk.CTkLabel(
            master=frame_item,
            text=text,
            width=width
        ).pack(side="left", padx=20)

    entries = {
        "cantidad": ctk.CTkEntry(master=frame_item, width=60, placeholder_text="Cantidad"),
        "empleado": ctk.CTkEntry(master=frame_item, width=100, placeholder_text="Empleado"),
        "descripcion": ctk.CTkEntry(master=frame_item, width=150, placeholder_text="Descripción")
    }

    for entry in entries.values():
        entry.pack(side="left", padx=10)

    self.seleccion_productos[producto[2]] = ProductoSeleccionado(
        check_var=check_var,
        entry_cantidad=entries["cantidad"],
        entry_empleado=entries["empleado"],
        entry_descripcion=entries["descripcion"],
        stock=producto[5]
    )

def _procesar_salida_productos(self):
    for codigo, datos in self.seleccion_productos.items():
        if datos.check_var.get():
            try:
                cantidad = int(datos.entry_cantidad.get())
                if 0 < cantidad <= datos.stock:
                    base_datos.actualizar_stock(
                        codigo,
                        cantidad,
                        datos.entry_descripcion.get(),
                        datos.entry_empleado.get()
                    )
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Error: Cantidad no válida para el producto {codigo}")

Tengo un seccion de historial de movimientos cuando retiro un producto de salida me muestra la cantidad reflejada en un treeview, el historial si lo carga de una forma rapida pero tambien pienso es por que no tiene el checkbox y no tiene un filtrado de busqueda sera porque los productos los esta llamando con un for?


PD: No fijarse en los codigo ni en el nombre son pruebas para ver si registraba los productos 

Dentro del primero método, tienes 2 veces base_datos.obtener_productos(), no estás trayendo TODOS los productos, 2 veces o si ?

En producto = base_datos.obtener_productos() y productos.extend(base_datos,obtener_productos())?el primero trae los productos y el otro es para actualizar la lista de productos si retiro un producto

Pero obtener_productos, trae todos los productos de nuevo ?

Lo primero es identificar donde está la tardanza, para no perder tiempo buscando la solución donde no está.
